# The term '<ScriptPath>\Move' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I've created a script which moves files and folders from one folder to another.  I've designed it in the PowerShell ISE and if I run it from there it works perfectly.

However when I run it from either Task Scheduler or the command prompt using

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass "C:\MilkImports\FileScripts\Move No Holdings Milk Files.ps1"
```

I get the following error

> C:\PSScripts\Move : The term 'C:\PSScripts\Move' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

The only reference to Move in my script is when I use Move-Item.

My script is as follows

```
$SQLServer = "xxx"
$SQLDatabase = "xxx"
$SQLUser = "xxx"
$SQLPassword = "xxx"
$SQLConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SQLCommand = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SQLDataAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$dtPIDs = New-Object System.Data.DataTable

$SQLQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT(PID) FROM table1 t1
             INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.CID = t2.CID
             WHERE CHARINDEX('UK', areaCode) > 0"

$SQLConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$SQLServer;Database=$SQLDatabase;Integrated Security=false;User ID=$SQLUser;Password=$SQLPassword;"
$SQLCommand.Connection = $SQLConnection
$SQLCommand.CommandText = $SQLQuery
$SQLDataAdapter.SelectCommand = $SQLCommand
$SQLDataAdapter.Fill($dtPIDs)

foreach($Row in $dtPIDs)
{
    $PID = $Row["PID"]

    $SourceFolder = Join-Path -Path "C:\Imports\NoHolding" -ChildPath $PID
    $DestinationFolder = Join-Path -Path "C:\Imports\Input" -ChildPath $PID

    if ((Test-Path $SourceFolder) -eq 1)
    {
        if ((Test-Path $DestinationFolder) -eq 0)
        {
            mkdir $DestinationFolder
        }

        $SourceFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Filter "*.dat"

        foreach ($SourceFile in $SourceFiles)
        {
            $DestinationFile = Join-Path -Path $DestinationFolder -ChildPath $SourceFile.Name

            Move-Item -Path $SourceFile.FullName -Destination $DestinationFile
        }
    }
}

$SourceFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Imports\NoHolding" -Filter "*.dat"

foreach ($SourceFile in $SourceFiles)
{
    $DestinationFile = Join-Path -Path "C:\Imports\Input" -ChildPath $SourceFile.Name

    Move-Item -Path $SourceFile.FullName -Destination $DestinationFile
}
```

Comment: What, exactly, are you typing on Powershell prompt? Are you working with paths containing spaces (like "c:\Imports\This and That\"). This sounds like a quotation or whitespace problem.

Comment: Forgot to include that.  I'm running it with C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass "C:\PSScripts\Move No Holdings Milk Files.ps1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-File` parameter:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\PSScripts\Move No Holdings Milk Files.ps1"
```

Comment: It is to mention that the latest betas of PowerShell 6.0.0 are switching parameter position 0 from now -Command to -File so it would have worked with these versions, but it is always the better decision to be clear what follows.